# Multiple sheets in a single Draw.io project

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to have multiple Draw.io sketch sheets in a single window divided by Tabs just like Excel or Google Spreadsheets have?

Answer (score 1):

It is.
At the bottom of the sketchpad you have the page number you are in (similar to sheet). just click the + sign next to the page number to add more pages.